# Java Regex: Matching the first Row that has asterisk in it

Tags: regex

Sample Data

> ```
>   A       B   C                                           
> BHD
> ```
>
> P 1  QPH              1 P
>   P 2  *PH              2 P
>   P 3  *PH     ZP  ZP   3 P
>   P 4  QPH     QPH QP   4 P
>     5  * H     * H *    5
>     6  * H     * H *    6
>     7  * H     * H *    7
>     8  Z H     Z H Z    8
>     9  * H     * H *    9
>    10  * H     * H *    10
>   W11  *UH     *UH *U   11W

I'm trying to extract the first row with "* H" in it (For example Row 5), But not getting any results
This is what i have tried so far

```
String result = sample Data
Pattern l =Pattern.compile(^  ([A-Z}|//s)? ?([0-9]{1,2})     (\\*)  [H] .*)
Matcher m =l.matcher(result);
If(m.find()){
 System.out.println( “The Row number is: “ m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: So you want to read the data line-by-line and return the line `5 * H * H * 5`? The method should take a `String` and return a `String`?

Comment: I want to return the row number (e.g.: "5"). This is my method name/layout:"public String findRow(String Data) throws Exception{"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you want to scan the `String` line-by-line and find the first line that contains `* H` then return its number.

The pattern for this is `\\*\\s+H`, you just need to find a line that contains that pattern:

```
public static int findStartH(final String input) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*\\s+H");
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
    for (int i = 1; scanner.hasNextLine(); ++i) {
        final String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (pattern.matcher(line).find()) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input does not contain required string.");
}
```

Quick test case:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String input = "Sample Data A B C\n"
            + "BHD\n"
            + "P 1 QPH 1 P\n"
            + "P 2 *PH 2 P\n"
            + "P 3 *PH ZP ZP 3 P\n"
            + "P 4 QPH QPH QP 4 P\n"
            + "5 * H * H * 5\n"
            + "6 * H * H * 6\n"
            + "7 * H * H * 7\n"
            + "8 Z H Z H Z 8\n"
            + "9 * H * H * 9\n"
            + "10 * H * H * 10\n"
            + "W11 *UH *UH *U 11W";
    System.out.println(findStarH(input));
}
```

Output:

```
7
```

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful, but i actually want to return the row number listed in the data i.e: "5" instead of 7.

Comment: @user3306992 it's returning `7` because that _is_ the row in the data in this case - count them.